Finding the maximum of $f(x) = \lim_{n \to\infty}n(x^{\sqrt[n]{x}}-x)$

What is the maximum of the function
$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to\infty}n(x^{\sqrt[n]{x}}-x)$$
for $0 \leq x \leq 1?$

I know that $f(e) = e$ and $f(1/e) = 1/e$ (where $e$ is Euler's constant).
The maximum is approximately $0.541$ for approximately $x= 0.135$.
I'm looking for a nice closed form if there is one, but a fast method of calculation is also appreciated.

Why was the display style and line break edited out; to make the question seem shorter?

@TymaGaidash: Please flag that to moderators. It is happening almost on a daily basis.

$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to\infty}n(x^{\sqrt[n]{x}}-x)=x\lim_{n\to0}\frac{x^{x^n-1}-1}n$$
This looks like $\ln(x)=\lim_\limits{n\to0}\frac{x^n-1}n$ which can solved by differentiating, so the same is done to $g(x)=\lim_\limits{n\to0}\frac{x^{x^n-1}-1}n$ using limit properties:
$$g’(x)=\lim_{n\to0} x^{x^n-2}\frac{(n\ln(x)+1)x^n-1}n= \lim_{n\to0} x^{x^n-2}\left(\lim_{n\to0}\frac{x^n-1}n+\lim_{n\to0}x^n\ln(x)\right)=\frac{2\ln(x)}x$$
Integrating and noticing $g(1)=0$, one finds:
$$f(x)=x\int_1^xg(x)dx=x\ln^2(x)$$
Therefore, the extrema are at $f’(x)=\ln(x)(\ln(x)+2)=0$. Since the maximum is at $x\approx0.135$, it is:
$$\left(\frac1{e^2},\frac4{e^2}\right)$$

Fix $0<x<1$.
$$\frac{x^{x^{1/n}}-x}{1/n}=\frac{x^{1+x^{1/n}-1}-x}{x^{1/n}-1}\frac{x^{1/n}-1}{1/n}$$
As $\lim x^{1/n}-1=0$ and $\phi:t\mapsto x^t$ is differentiable for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and  $\phi'(t)=\phi(t)\log x$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^{1+x^{1/n}-1}-x}{x^{1/n}-1}&\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}=\phi'(1)=x\log x\\
\frac{x^{1/n}-1}{1/n}&\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\phi'(0)=\log x
\end{align}
Thus $G(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{x^{1/n}}-x}{1/n}=x(\log x)^2$. Can you continue from here?

$$f = n[x^{x^{1/n}}-x]$$
It is convenient to take a factor $x$ out off the brackets.
$$f = nx [x^{(-1 + x^{1/n})}-1]$$
Now write the $x$'s in the exponential terms as $e^{ln(x)}$.
$$f = nx[e^{ln(x)(-1+e^{ln(x)/n})} -1]$$
Expand the exponential terms up to linear order and take the limit of $n$ to infinity. We get:
$$f = x \space (ln(x))^{2}$$
This function has a maximum for $x = 1/e^{2}$. The corresponding value is $f = 4/e^{2}$.
